# Check for existence before SaveChanges in Entity Framework 6.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, unique-constraint

I need to process a text file coming from an external system. My code (C#) looks like this:

```
foreach (var parsedFileLine in parsedFileData)
{
    var container = context.Containers
        .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Label == parsedFileLine.ccoid);
    if (container == null)
    {
        container = context.Containers.Create();
        container.Label = parsedFileLine.ccoid;
        // More initialization logic
        ...
        context.Containers.Insert(container);
    }
    // Some more processing
    ...
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

The DB has a Unique constraint on the Label column. If I receive a file with one line for each container, everything works fine. But when I receive a file with 2+ lines referring to a new container, I get a Contraint Violation.

The problem is that my check for existence fails for the second file line (since SaveChanges has not yet been called, thus new Container has not yet been created in the DB), so I try to create again the container. When the changes are committed the DB throws exception because I'm trying to insert two rows with same Label.

I first thought of using Find(), but since this is a new entity, I don't have a Key to search for. Putting the SaveChanges inside the loop is not an option either, since I need transactional processing of the files. And changing the PK to be Label is not an option because of the amount of work involved.

Any ideas on how this problem could be solved?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to write a preprocess Method.

This method will contain your current DB Container Values, And also and another tempContainer that stores just added Container values.
Check both containers before insert.

```
List MyDBList;
List MyTempList;

Foreach(item)
{
  checkMyDBList(item);
  checkMyTempList(item);

  if(checkbothlist)
  MyTempList.add(item);
}
add MyTempList to MyDBList
save MyDBList
```